# Displaying the only the last 6 files of a category in article using Phoca Download Plugin

Tags: phocagallery

Phoca Download has a plugin to show a list of files in certain category using `{phocadownload view=filelist|id=XX|limit=YY}`, where XX is the number of category and YY is the number of files to show. For the particular case, I would like to show the last 6 files uploaded to certain category.

I would like to show certain categories to show on certain title ascendant ordering and other to show on certain title descendant ordering, but it is possible to use only one ordering on Phoca Download settings.

There is no parameter in [Phoca Download Plugin documentation](https://www.phoca.cz/documents/51-phoca-download-plugin/228-displaying-phoca-download-plugin) that let us change file ordering particularly on that view.

Do you know how so solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found only a fix on code change.

1. On plugins/content/phocadownload/phocadownload.php copy from `case 'filelist':` to `break;` and paste bellow changing `filelist` to `filelistdt`;
2. Replace `$fileOrdering       = PhocaDownloadOrdering::getOrderingText($ordering, 3);` on that case to `$fileOrdering         = 'a.title DESC';`
3. On Phoca Download Settings, use title ascendant for default ordering;
4. On the use of Phoca Download Plugin, use `{phocadownload view=filelist|id=XX|limit=YY}` for title ascendant ordering or `{phocadownload view=filelistdt|id=XX|limit=YY}` for titls descendant ordering.
5. For the last 6, use `{phocadownload view=filelistdt|id=XX|limit=6}`

The only issue I found with that is when Phoca Download Plugin would be updated, that changes will be overwritten :(